# How to draw a custom map on top of base layer

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, map-drawing

I'm looking for the easiest way to draw a custom layer and export it as a tile cache.   Basically what I would like to be able to do is load a base layer, and then draw objects and annotations on top of it and export these objects and annotations as a raster (GeoTIFF) than I can them run through MapTiler.  I'd like my custom map to include both polygons, circles, and text, sort of like using a georeferenced Adobe Illustrator.   What's the best process to do this?

I'm thinking QGis since I have experience there, but maybe there are other tools where this is more straightforward

Answer (score 1):

I think if you saved your QGIS base map (map view, not print composer) as a TIFF/TIF (this will save the .TIFW - which is a world file / georeferencing file), you could bring it into GIMP or PhotoShop or whatever and make your annotations there.

As long as the extent, size, shape of the TIF doesn't change, the TIF should draw in any mapping package with those new annotations just fine...

Comment: ok worth a try.  i'm thinking about warping.. if I create and display the TIFF in the same CRC, I can probably avoid warping?

Comment: not sure about that one! can you give more of an explanation?